# Web Service question

Tags: integration, webservices

I am new to Web Services and we are starting to approach the idea of integrating with a WS from another of our systems.

Ideally, we would have a two-way real-time integration which would allow for SF field values to be updated upon change in the other system, as well as creation of new records in the other system by Salesforce.

I'm not sure exactly what is the best approach for this. For now, I'm guessing it will be a REST connection. But everything I have seen so far is showing the integration to be on demand where callouts are done upon the click of a button. But as I said, we would want this connection to be real-time, updating a Salesforce field upon any change in the other system.

Can you provide some guidance on this ? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This question is too broad, but here's my take.

> we would have a two-way real-time integration which would allow for SF field values to be updated upon change in the other system, as well as creation of new records in the other system by Salesforce.

Breaking this up further as:

> 1. allow for SF field values to be updated upon change in the other system
> 2. creation of new records in the other system by Salesforce

While the best approach is to use a *Middleware* for any integration scenarios, but sometimes that's not feasible because of multiple reasons.

If I were to design based on the requirements above. I would have done something as below:

1. I would have the External System make changes in Salesforce whenever there is a change at their end. Reason being - this will reduce complexity for Salesforce to keep on polling the external system to listen for any changes.

   How will External System make call into Salefsorce? It depends on WHAT will be updated and also HOW will it be updated. If it's all about making updates on say records using their Id, any *standard REST API* will work here. But if you have more complicated logic of updating records, then you may want to expose a *custom REST API* for that purpose.
2. For this scenario, it will be just a callout from Salesforce to External System. And it totally depends on WHEN is the callout required, and HOW has the external system exposed their services (as a REST API or SOAP API). So let's say if you need to make the callout depending on #1 above, then as soon as the respective record is updated, you just go ahead and make the callout to the external system.

   One thing to consider here is that you cannot really achieve two-way integration real time if you are using triggers here (as soon as the record is updated and if you make the callout to the external system from a trigger). Utlimately, it all depends on when do you need to make the callout from Salesforce.

Comment: #1) Yes - that's the approach I was hoping to go with . - and yes, I would want Salesforce records to be updated by the external system. So, I guess it would just be a callout by the external system onto the Apex REST API ... ? If so, we wouldn't be able to use the Salesforce record ID as the basis of the external system's search to update the proper record since there wouldn't be one. Would it work if we were basic it on a field in Salesforce which is an external ID field - or any other field ? 

With this one-way type of scenario, what would be the Apex requirements on the Salesforce?

Comment: Yes, it will work on External Id as well. From Apex requirements perspective, as long as you can address with any OOTB APIs, go for that. Consider building anything custom only when you are out of options. For External Id upserts, you may like to take a look at -- [**SObject Rows by External ID**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_upsert.htm)

Comment: ok - so if I understand correctly it's just a matter of giving the correct endpoint to the external system....? No Apex needed ? In the example at the bottom of the page you gave of SOOBJECTs by Ext ID - I looked at the Upserting page and it looks like all you have to do is give the proper endpoint, cust object, and external ID field to the support of the other system and they should be able to do the upserts with a PUT method in a callout from their end...? (although they don't specifically show a PUT method being used).

Comment: That’s correct. Those are just standard endpoints, so need to write anything custom.

Comment: In the example I'm looking at in the "Insert or Update(Upsert).." page I referenced they show an endpoint as "......./MerchandiseEXTID__c/123 -H "Authorization: Bearer Token" - How exactly does that authorization work ? The "Token" they're referencing isn't the token which can be created w/ a SF account, is it ? And what is the "123" in the thread ?

Comment: I would classify that as a completely separate question outside of the current one. You will need to go through some details as how you can get authentication token and then invoke REST API calls. There are lots of resources around, so you will find many resources to get started on that direction.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right. It is a whole different subject. Thank you very much for all of your help Jayant !

Comment: btw - I don't know whether to mark your answer or @sfdcfox solution as the best because you both are answering different parts of what I was asking. So please don't get offended if I don't mark either as the "best answer"   :-)

Answer (score 2):

We have a lot of ways to do near-real-time data syncing within Salesforce. The limitations of your external system may affect the final result. For example, you could make a Platform Event that you fire off from Salesforce for changes to your external system (which would set up an event listener), Workflow Outbound Messages, Flows, Streaming API, or Apex code... And from the external system, it might be a Platform Event, SOAP call, REST call, etc.

Each have pros and cons, but at least most of them offer robust automatic retry mechanisms and are designed to minimize database contention. Mind you, one significant limitation is that it will not strictly be *real-time* all the time. If there's too much traffic, updates to the external system will be delayed. This is to prevent excessive use of resources and database contention. It will be best-effort, but there's no guarantee of 100% real-time performance.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're suggesting here (keep in mind I said I was new to WS) - in your scenario, is the Platform Event for changes to external system as in changes IN the external system or changes in Salesforce TO the external system ? I can't tell if you're suggesting Salesforce would send changes in bulk to the external system - or if it is retrieving in bulk.

Comment: @Zoom_v they can go both ways. The external system can receive them, and Salesforce can listen for events from the external system. Platform Events are a bit like an Enterprise Service Bus.

Comment: So, if I just want the external system to update the record fields in Salesforce do I need to also set up a Platform Event in Salesforce and subscribe to the event of a changed field on their side also ? Or would it just be up to them to set up a Platform Event on their end to send PUT callouts to my REST API ?

Comment: @Zoom_v it really depends on what the external system is capable of. I can't speak for them. They might choose to use Platform Events, the SOAP API, the REST API, a custom REST API written in Apex, Bulk API, etc. You need to identify which capabilities you have before you can determine the best approach. There's a variety of different tools.